# How to insert for each Student Id 5 Interest Ids?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to be able to insert five Interest Ids in the Student_Interest table for each student Id.

I tried that, but instead of getting 30 lines I get 72 (6 students in Student table and 12 interest in Interest table) :

```
INSERT INTO Student_Interest (Id_Student, Id_Interest, Score)
SELECT 
    Id_Student
    ,Id_Interest
    ,ABS(Checksum(NewID()) % 5) + 1
FROM Student, Interest
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is `CROSS JOIN` :

```
INSERT INTO Student_Interest (Id_Student, Id_Interest, Score)
     SELECT  Id_Student, Id_Interest, i.Score
     FROM Student s CROSS JOIN
          (SELECT TOP (5) Score FROM Interest ORDER BY NEWID()) i;
```